# $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \widetilde{\mu}_n)^2 = n\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n$?

Tags: probability

Is the equation true? Looks like but I don't really know why ...

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \widetilde{\mu}_n)^2 = n\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n$$

Seems like I will get

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \widetilde{\mu}_n)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n})^2$$

But I dont get how do I get $n\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n$. Reason why I think the expression equals $n\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n$ is in the book, it seems like

$$\frac{1}{(\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n)^3} \sum(x_i - \widetilde{\mu}_n)^2 = \frac{n}{(\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n)^2}$$ so

$$\sum(x_i - \widetilde{\mu}_n)^2 = n\widetilde{\sigma}^2_n$$

if i cross multiply

---

*see line marked with red arrow near bottom of image*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your definition seems inconsistent with what the book writes.

Comment: Why would think that $\sum_i  (x_i -\tilde{\mu}_n)=\tilde{\sigma}_n^2$? In fact $\sum_i  (x_i -\tilde{\mu}_n)=0$.

Comment: @StefanHansen, I was thinking if $\sum_i  (x_i -\tilde{\mu}_n)^2=\tilde{\sigma}_n^2$ then $\frac{1}{(\tilde{\sigma}_n^2)^3} \cdot \tilde{\sigma}_n^2 = \frac{1}{(\tilde{\sigma}_n^2)^2}$. There was a typo ... I missed out the power of 2 i think

Comment: Ok updated my question, I think theres some typo previously ... also missed out the $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. It is the ML estimator for the variance. Use $(n-1)$ instead of $n$ and you get the sample variance. Just look at the equation right above the Hessian, there it says this is true.